# Excel Formula calculation based on pervious matching criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Column A contains reference value Column B is a data unique to that Row Column C is where I need a formula to pull a prior Row's Column B data if the Reference Column A has a "Y" in it. Note: Rows between "Y" in live data set can range between 3 and 5 is what the output would need to look like as above picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Excel O365, you can use:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=IF(A2="Y",XLOOKUP("Y",A$1:A1,B$1:B1,"",0,-1),"")
```

In earlier versions of Excel, try:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/((A$1:A1="Y")*(A2="Y")),B$1:B1),"")
```